# Handle or listen to when an IntentService stops

Tags: android, service, android-service, intentservice

I have an IntentService that uploads pictures and text to a server. I am launching a service with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
startService(intent);
```

In the service, at various points within **onHandleIntent(Intent intent)**, I am calling **stopSelf()** to terminate the service. I want to know when the service has stopped and handle changes in the UI when it has stopped. An additional caveat is that the user may be in a different activity than they were when the service started.

How can I listen for when the service is stopped?

Comment: you can't per se. you can use a broadcast, though.

Comment: or, if your service changes data in a contentprovider, you can be notified by the contentprovider itself that the data changed. (which makes more sense)

Comment: @njzk2 So using a broadcast receiver, I would just have to instantiate the broadcast receiver in any activity that needs to listen to the service?

Comment: exactly, yes you would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am calling stopSelf() to terminate the service

Why? If you want to skip over logic, that's fine, but please allow `onHandleIntent()` to finish normally and call `stopSelf()` on its own accord. For example, there may be more `Intent` commands queued up to be processed.

> How can I listen for when the service is stopped?

Use an event bus, such as `LocalBroadcastManager` or [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought I had to call stopSelf(), I was not aware that the service calls it on itself when it is done handling the intent(s)

Comment: @clocksmith: Yes, `stopSelf()` is automatic. Comes for free with every instance of `IntentService`. :-)